# Try, except with break

Tags: dictionary, input, break, try-except

I'm trying to create a code that append inputs from user into the alimentos_taco dictionary.

The idea of the code is: there is a book where people search for specific foods, which have specific number (ex.: rice = 78). So the person type in the first input, which is reserved for the number of the food (ex.: 78) and, after this, the person type the second input, which is reserved for the food grams. If there are no more food number to type, the person should press enter, to stop appending numbers to the dict.
But i'm having issues because when I type ENTER, the loop starts back.
Sorry for the bad english.

```
alimentos_taco = {}
alimentos_taco["Número"] = []
alimentos_taco["Quantidade (em gramas)"] = []

while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("Type the food number (or type ENTER if you don't have more foods"))
        if number == "":
            break
        alimentos_taco["Número"].append(number)
    except ValueError:
        print("Type a valid number:")
        continue
    try:  
        quantidade = int(input("Type the food quantity (in grams)"))
        alimentos_taco["Quantidade (em gramas)"].append(quantidade)
    except ValueError:
        print("Type only numbers")
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you are trying to compare your input with the empty string after you try to convert it to an integer. So when you input an empty string, there is an error before your code can get to the if statement. By converting to an integer after the if statement I think the problem is solved.

```
alimentos_taco = {}
alimentos_taco["Número"] = []
alimentos_taco["Quantidade (em gramas)"] = []

while True:
    try:
        number = input("Type the food number (or type ENTER if you don't have more foods")
        if number == "":
            break
        
        alimentos_taco["Número"].append(int(number))
    except ValueError:
        print("Type a valid number:")
        continue
    try:  
        quantidade = int(input("Type the food quantity (in grams)"))
        alimentos_taco["Quantidade (em gramas)"].append(quantidade)
    except ValueError:
        print("Type only numbers")
        continue
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks man, you helped a lot